# How to concatenate column values from each group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`

```
    df <- structure(list(GENE = c("TNFRSF4", "TNFRSF4", "VWA1", "VWA1", 
"PEX10", "CEP104"), KEY.varID = c("chr1:1213738:G:A", "chr1:1232280:T:C", 
"chr1:1435798:T:TGGCGCGGAGC", "chr1:1437401:C:G", "chr1:2406791:C:CT", 
"chr1:3844977:G:A")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(GENE) %>%
  mutate(all_variants = paste(KEY.varID, collapse = ","))
```

Result I want:

```
GENE                  KEY.varID
TNFRSF4           chr1:1213738:G:A, chr1:1232280:T:C
VWA1              chr1:1435798:T:TGGCGCGGAGC, chr1:1437401:C:G
PEX10          chr1:2406791:C:CT
CEP104           chr1:3844977:G:A
```

Comment: In your code, you need `summarise` instead of `mutate` i.e. `df %>% group_by(GENE) %>% summarise(all_variants = paste(KEY.varID, collapse = ","))`

Comment: `aggregate(.~GENE, df, toString)` or even `df %>% group_by(GENE) %>% summarise(all_variants = toString(KEY.varID))`

Comment: @akrun That did not work.

Comment: @MAPK It is working fine for me.  Maybe you loaded `plyr`, change `summarise` to `dplyr::summarise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>% 
  group_by(GENE) %>% 
  summarise(KEY.varID = str_c(KEY.varID, collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  as.data.table

#>       GENE                                    KEY.varID
#> 1:  CEP104                             chr1:3844977:G:A
#> 2:   PEX10                            chr1:2406791:C:CT
#> 3: TNFRSF4           chr1:1213738:G:A, chr1:1232280:T:C
#> 4:    VWA1 chr1:1435798:T:TGGCGCGGAGC, chr1:1437401:C:G
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is already a data.table; you can simply paste/collapse, and use `by`

```
library(data.table)
df[, .(KEY.varID = paste(KEY.varID, collapse = ",")), by=GENE]
```

Output:

```
      GENE                                   KEY.varID
1: TNFRSF4           chr1:1213738:G:A,chr1:1232280:T:C
2:    VWA1 chr1:1435798:T:TGGCGCGGAGC,chr1:1437401:C:G
3:   PEX10                           chr1:2406791:C:CT
4:  CEP104                            chr1:3844977:G:A
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution is

```r
tapply(df$KEY.varID, df$GENE, paste, collapse = ",") |> 
    (\(x) data.frame(GENE = names(x), KEY.varID = unname(x)))()
#R>      GENE                                   KEY.varID
#R> 1  CEP104                            chr1:3844977:G:A
#R> 2   PEX10                           chr1:2406791:C:CT
#R> 3 TNFRSF4           chr1:1213738:G:A,chr1:1232280:T:C
#R> 4    VWA1 chr1:1435798:T:TGGCGCGGAGC,chr1:1437401:C:G
```